# Pick a random element from array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to set background-color with jQUery animate function and i need to pick a random element from array.

```
$(".menu li").hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({borderBottomColor:"#81C6DD"}, 200)
}, function() {
  $(this).animate({borderBottomColor:"#D8D9DC"}, 200)
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you don't want to randomize the array, sounds like you want to pick a random element from the array each time. Assuming your array of colors is called `colors`, use:

```
var color = colors[Math.floor(colors.length * Math.random())];
```

Although I question why you'd want to do that. Random colors sounds like a recipe for a really ugly and potentially confusing UI.

Comment: Thanks.. I have exactly colors and with every of them it'll look good.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with lot of color values and use any function in javascript which generate an random number between a range, in our case we need to generate a random number between o to array length of color array. And then use this random number as a key in color array and put this in place of color.